# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

With `OkHttp` library, application is facing following `SocketTimeoutException` issue. If request size is less, then it is working fine(Less than 1MB). I am getting this exception within 10 seconds, even my socket timeout(`readTimeout`) value is much higher. It is consistently failing for a request(Size is 1.8MB). When I executed a request with `HttpUrlConnection` it is working fine. What could be a possible reason of failure?

```
   03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:158)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1xStream.java:286)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:96)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$2.writeTo(RequestBody.java:96)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:704)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
    03-29 12:16:38.997 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at com.mobizio.api.BaseApi.sendOkHttpRequest(BaseApi.java:81)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at com.mobizio.api.BaseApi.doInBackground(BaseApi.java:45)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at com.mobizio.api.BaseApi.doInBackground(BaseApi.java:30)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:759)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:80)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
    03-29 12:16:38.998 32066-4018/com.mobile W/System.err:  ... 20 more
```

Comment: Give your client a larger read time out value. Seems that time out is happening when the stream is read from the socket.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I already set Socket timeout to 15 minutes still I am facing this issue

Answer (score 72):

For OkHttp 3 the default value for OkHttp is 10 seconds. You can increase the timeout to 30 seconds.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
```

Comment: I already set the connection timeout value to 30 seconds and socket timeout value to 15 minutes. Still I am facing the same issue and app is getting above exception within 10 seconds

Comment: @Vivek did you find a solution?

Comment: @DBragion As per documentation provided by Square https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes. It is suggested that don't use this post string method  if request size is more that 1MiB. You can fallback to HttpUrlConnection method or you need to implement post streaming at described in the document.

Comment: @Vivek -- did you ever find a solution?  I'm experiencing something similar.

Comment: No implemente post streaming or use httpurlconnection

Comment: I have set to 5 min Still Im getting this issue

Answer (score 59):

I solved that problem increasing `writeTimeout()`.

Try:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // connect timeout
.writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
.readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // read timeout

okHttpClient = builder.build();
```

Comment: Setting also writeTimeout solved the problem, thanks :)

Comment: If we want to upload file, we have to change the default writeTimeout as mentioned above.

Answer (score 22):

this resolved my problem:

```
OkHttpClient innerClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // connect timeout
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // read timeout
            .build();
```

Comment: How is this any different than what others have commented?

Comment: There are no more setters like the first two (setConnectTimeout & setReadTimeout), and I think mine is more organized :) Also, none is marked as resolved ;)

Comment: Saved my day. I was about to mess around on the internet

Comment: I think its the prettiest solution so far

Answer (score 8):

You need to understand that only adding this won't solve your problem:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

If you are using **Kotlin + Retrofit + Coroutines** then just use `try` and `catch` for network operations like,

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val userListResponseModel = apiEndPointsInterface.usersList()
            returnusersList(userListResponseModel)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Where, Exception is type of `kotlin` and not of `java.lang`

This will handle every exception like,

1. HttpException
2. SocketTimeoutException
3. FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher etc

Here is my `usersList()` function

```
@GET(AppConstants.APIEndPoints.HOME_CONTENT)
suspend fun usersList(): UserListResponseModel
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this for Kotlin

```
 val client1 = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // read timeout
                .addInterceptor(
                    BasicAuthInterceptor(
                        AmvaccAppConstants.AUTHENTICATE_USER_NAME, AmvaccAppConstants.AUTHENTICATE_USER_PASSWORD
                    )
                )
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using Retrofit and Kotlin then use following code:
    var BASE_URL:String="Your URL"
    val clientSetup = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
        .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // read timeout
        .build()

    val getClientApi: ApiInterface
        get() {
            var retrofit: Retrofit =  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(clientSetup)
                .build()
        }
```

Comment: This one helped me but can you please tell what is default time set for timeout? and is there any other clean method to avoid this problem?

Comment: normally http requests will not take that longer like 1 minute. Its better to fail and retry than increase timeout drastically. it will only increase the avg success time

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding **ping interval** to OkHttp helps a lot in reducing number of **SocketTimeoutExceptions** in the app.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .pingInterval(3, SECONDS)
        .build()
```

but i am not sure if these timeouts were related to request size.
I mentioned it also in [this issue on github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3974) reported to OkHttp library

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing the timeout is like putting a bandage on it, it will not solve the problem, there is a reason why this is happening, if you are happening to use OkHTTP you will find that this line

```
 override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
       var request = chain.request()
       ...
}
```

Excecutes an internal proceed method inside the okHttp library, this proceed method throws an `IOException`

```
interface Chain {
    fun request(): Request

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun proceed(request: Request): Response

    /**
     * Returns the connection the request will be executed on. This is only available in the chains
     * of network interceptors; for application interceptors this is always null.
     */
    fun connection(): Connection?

    fun call(): Call

 ...
```

To solve this issue, you must run this on a try catch function and return a mocked response error code with the message, so the team working behind of it can access its error and debug easily, instead of crashing the user app.

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        return try {
            
         var request = chain.request()

        } catch(e: IOException) {
          
            Response.Builder()
            .code(500)
            .message("Request failed with: $e.message")
            .build()
}
```

Doing so you can catch any IOException, `SocketTiemoutException` is one of them, but it could be any in the future.

Comment: How we can test this case?

Answer (score -1):

Run into a Run Catching

```
runCatching {
       service
}
 .map {
       if (it.isSuccessful && it.body() != null) {
           Success(Unit)
       } else {
           Error(Failure.AuthError.error(it.errorBody()))
       }
}
 .getOrElse {
       Error(Failure.Throwable(it))
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Check if your url is correct. This error can be because of wrong url line

Comment: What if server down? Then it behaves same like wrong URL as response won't be arriving from server. So setting proper URL is not the solution.